# Adding a subview that stays in place as you navigate through views

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I am looking to create a subview that looks like a banner drop down view from the Navigation Bar.

[image: example 1]    or like this    [image: example 2]

I feel like I see this effect all the time but have been struggling for a while to recreate this. I have it working on single view applications but I would like it to stay in place as I navigate from view to view. Right now I have the view setup in the storyboard and would like use this because I had issues attempting this programatically.

To create this "drop down banner view" and have it stay in place (until the user dismisses it) as a user navigates from screen to screen I see two solutions, each of which I have stumped myself on.

**Create my own master view as the window.rootViewController**
I see this as the cleaner solution in the end, but a bit harder to implement. Would it be possible to create a blank UIView as the rootViewController and whenever the app needs to drop down an alertBanner it could tell the rootController to do so? The view hierarchy would be something like

window -> masterViewController -> alertBannerController -> Navigation Controller -> otherViewControllers

but I cannot seem to have this set up the proper way.

**Create an instance of my AlertBannerView from a subclass of the UINavigationController**
Instead of calling the method to create a dropDownBanner from the rootViewController another option I see is subclassing the navigationController to be able to drop down this subview. This way it could still persist as the user navigates around views.

Once again I am having problems setting this up properly to work with the existing NavigationControllers

**Conclusion**

- I do not know what is the best approach here.
- This is different than the Apple Push Notifications drop down screen because I would like to customize it for the apps UI
- Any tips on how to properly set up a custom view as the rootViewController would be great (where do I do this? what methods do I need to call?)
- The problem to solve here is to have the alert banner view remain in the window until the user dismisses it even if they are navigating from screen to screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on which version of iOS you're working with, yeah there are a lot of possibilities and ways of doing this.  In fact, there are a *lot* of people who already have.

Best place for getting some ideas on how to attack this problem, to me, is by looking at an existing solution.  CocoaControls is a great place for this.

For instance, here is a relatively recent one:  https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mpgnotification

And here is a list of a bunch of them ( they aren't sorted in any particular order unfortunately though ) : https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=notification

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I don't know why I wasn't able to find these. What search terms were you using? Thank you!

Comment: No problem!  If you mean search term from google, I didn't use one actually.  Cocoacontrols was recommended by a book I had read a few years back.  If you mean search term on cocoacontrols, I just used "notification".  There very well may be other types too under a different search term so you may want to just search around or try different terms